# Change the column names of the data frame only for display purpose

Tags: r

Is there a way to change the names of the column headers of a data frame only for display purpose. For example

iris data has below default columns

```
ini_col <- c("Sepal.Length","Sepal.Width","Petal.Length","Petal.Width" ,"Species")
```

In case if I need to change it to below new columns. But only display purpose. Meaning, the reference of the old columns should not go away. For example I should still be able to execute `iris[["Species"]]` and not `iris[["Category"]]`

```
new_col <- c("Sep Len","Sep Wid","Pet Len","Pet Wid","Category")
```

```
head(iris)
         Sep Len     Sep Wid     Pet Len     Pet Wid Category 
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

We can actually make use of below code 
Code 1 below

```
mtcars2 <- 
  set_label(mtcars,
            am = "Automatic",
            mpg = "Miles per gallon",
            cyl = "Cylinders",
            qsec = "Quarter mile time")
```

But I have a dataframe where in there are old columns and new columns. Can we make this dataframe use in Code 1 above

```
df
Old COl    new COl
am         Automatic
mpg    Miles per gallon
cyl       Cylinders
qsec   Quarter mile time
```

Can we use this dataframe in executing Code1?

Comment: Thanks. But will the old reference change. Somwhere in Shiny application, Can I execute ````iris[["Species"]]````

Comment: Meaning, New columns is only display purpose that is it

Comment: Hi, maybe this approach would work? https://stackoverflow.com/a/51444998/7347699

Comment: The [labelVector](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/labelVector/vignettes/labelVector.html) package looks promising. I've never used it, and since you're talking about Shiny in comments it probably depends heavily on what functions/packages you're using to display the data.

Comment: @GregorThomas Awesome thanks. But I have new columns in the form of dataframe (please see edited question). Can we keep this dataframe and execute setlabel?

Comment: No idea - as I've said, never used it.

Comment: Cool. Anyways thanks a lot

Comment: @GregorThomas FYI by using set label, even the old names gets repeated :(

Comment: How are you are you displaying the data? What functions/packages are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As linked in a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51432502/replace-column-names-in-kable-r-markdown), `kable` from the `knitr` package makes it easy to change the names for display without altering the data frame:

```
knitr::kable(head(iris), 
             col.names = c("Speal length", "Speal Width",
"Petal Length", "Petal Width", "Species"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Actually I was trying in without kable. Already shiny application in been built. Now it is difficultr to change the entire logic.

Comment: Okay, no problem. Would be worth including such details (i.e. you are using shiny) in your original question so that people can provide the right support